# mvc No se encuentra el recurso

Tags: mvc, configuración

Uso VS 2015 tengo un controlador llamado **ClientesRWController** y una vista Index2, en el Route config tengo:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ClientesRW",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ClientesRW", action = "Index2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Pero sale el error no se encuentra el recurso

Comment: Ya probaste agregar la palabra Controller al name?

Comment: Cierto, con eso funcionó. Gracias